# How to get the first available Motherboard's serial number?

Tags: vb.net

Respected Sir,
 How to get the first available motherboards' serial number in this script ?

```
 Private Function SystemSerialNumber() As String
        ' Get the Windows Management Instrumentation object.
        Dim wmi As Object = GetObject("WinMgmts:")

        ' Get the "base boards" (mother boards).
        Dim serial_numbers As String = ""
        Dim mother_boards As Object = wmi.InstancesOf("Win32_BaseBoard")
        For Each board As Object In mother_boards
            serial_numbers &= ", " & board.SerialNumber
        Next board
        If serial_numbers.Length > 0 Then serial_numbers = serial_numbers.Substring(2)

        Return serial_numbers
    End Function
```

Yours faithfully

Murulimadhav

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the appropriate .Net classes in the [`System.Management`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Management(v=vs.110).aspx) Namespace they will return a [`ManagmentObjectCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobjectcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) that you can use an index on to return the first instance. Unfortunately with the nature of this class you still need to use late binding which will keep you from turning on `Option Strict`.  You will need to add the `System Management` Namespace to your project references and also import it into your class.

```
Imports System.Management
Public Class Form1
    Public Sub New()

        InitializeComponent()
        TextBox1.Text = SystemSerialNumber()

    End Sub

    Private Function SystemSerialNumber() As String
        Dim value As String = ""
        Dim baseBoard As ManagementClass = New ManagementClass("Win32_BaseBoard")
        Dim board As ManagementObjectCollection = baseBoard.GetInstances()
        If board.Count > 0 Then
            value = board(0)("SerialNumber")
            If value.Length > 0 Then value = value.Substring(2)
        End If            
        Return value

    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: @MarkHall Thanks for the code. Do you know why on some models we only get and empty string?

Comment: @fedeteka That information is usually stored in CMOS by the manufacturer. If it isn't there then my guess is that it wasn't put there. You may be able to find an utility that would be able to update the information.

Comment: @MarkHall Thanks!